# Get KEY from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, key, key-value

Following JSON : https://api.myjson.com/bins/3yz34

I was thinking I might use an internal ID for a key (which simplifies looping through several entities and setting up data gathering) and use a value for display. However, I cannot get the value of the key.

```
            $.each(tabledata.Companies, function (){
                company = this;
                alert(company);
                var test = Object.keys( company );
                console.log(test);
            });
```

Object.keys() just gives me the number of characters in the value.

```
var test = Object.keys( company );
```

Returns:

```
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

Which seems to be the number of characters from the value in the key-value pair? Pretty stuck on this one, any ideas? Or maybe setup the JSON differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you trim down the example JSON to something digestible?

Comment: What does your `tabledata` look like?  Typically you can use `$.each(tabledata.Companies, function (key, value){` and it will return the necessary keys and values to use inside your function.... Have you tried that?

Comment: I did try that, actually. To no avail.

Comment: It looks like an array

Comment: `Object.keys(company)` is returning integer keys because `company` is an Array. It's first key is 0, the next is 1, and so on.

Comment: in the $.each callback, you are not specifying anything. `function(i, item)` will give you `i` for each index and `item` for the item at that index. Would be immensely helpful if you gave a sample data. That return you posted is all the indexes of the array of data.

Comment: @ochi: sorry, but you were right! I am not worthy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of your loop function to pass in the parameters

`$.each(tabledata.Companies, function(key, value) {...}`

See demo below

**DEMO UPDATED** based on comments

```js
var tabledata = {
  "Companies": {
    "8df135f4-db42-486c-8d8c-fbbdd561c25e": "Phillips",
    "47d946e3-56db-4bc7-8472-3809eb48506d": "Bauknecht",
    "3ae13b97-7a09-4342-8953-c1d5a55687db": "Capitol",
    "fb017214-dbc1-4b71-8080-4f9b530f4b49": "Bosch",
    "50ede412-4eb0-429b-8d73-a1bfef41ebbc": "LG Corp"
  },  
  "Pets": {
    "dog": "Snoopy",
    "cat": "Silvester",
    "bird": "Sweetie",
    "snake": "Snaker",
    "fish": "Goldie Locks"
  }

}

var attributeName="Companies";

$(function() {
  $.each(tabledata[attributeName], function(key, value) {
    console.log("KEY:" + key + " -> Value:" + value);
  });
  
  attributeName="Pets";
  
  $.each(tabledata[attributeName], function(key, value) {
    console.log("KEY:" + key + " -> Value:" + value);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Another derived question (while we're at it): How would it be possible to have the (tabledata.Companies) parameterized? Something like: var variable = Companies; Then call (tabledata.variable). Hope I am clear on this?

Comment: Great help. Much appreciated!